# Allowing initializer lists inside of a macro

Tags: c++, preprocessor

In a project I was working on there is a macro that logs an expression. I was tasked with adding the ability to pass multiple values into it and have each print by itself.
I've managed to get this working relatively easy with 1 through 5 arguments. It even works just fine being passed into a function still.

The problem I have now is that initializer lists no longer work. The project used variadic arguments to allow for array initialisation inside of it like `func(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1})`. Since I've implemented the multi arg things this no longer works because of the commas.

I'm aware that I can do `func((std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1}))` and this will work just fine but I know that this will not be liked as a work around. Is there a way I can get these to work without the extra brackets or to add in the extra brackets when needed?

Here's some relevant snippets :

```
// Intermediate macro "chooser"
#define func_x(x, A, B, C, D, E, Func, ...) Func

// Macro to be called and used by user
// First param must be blank to allow for 0 argument function
#define func(...) func_x(, ##__VA_ARGS__, \
  func_5(__VA_ARGS__), func_4(__VA_ARGS__), func_3(__VA_ARGS__), \
  func_2(__VA_ARGS__), func_1(__VA_ARGS__), func_0())

// Macros for 1 through 5 args, calls the func_VA macro.
#define func_1(A1) func_VA(A1)
#define func_2(A1, A2) func_1(A1), func_VA(A2)
#define func_3(A1, A2, A3) func_2(A1, A2), func_VA(A3)
#define func_4(A1, A2, A3, A4) func_3(A1, A2, A3), func_VA(A4)
#define func_5(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5) func_4(A1, A2, A3, A4), func_VA(A5)

// Prints expression and type
// We use a variadic macro to support commas inside expressions (e.g.
// initializer lists):
#define func_VA(...)                                                  \
  func_macro::DebugOutput(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #__VA_ARGS__) \
      .print(func_macro::type_name<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(), (__VA_ARGS__))
```

```
func(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1});
// Errors

func((std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1}));
// Works, but also prints the () when logging so not ideal. Better than nothing though.
```

I've been trying to slot brackets around certain parts of my macros to try and fix this but to no avail. Like `#define func_1(A1) func_VA((A1))` or similar.

EDIT : I've made some progress

Declaring `func_1` like `#define func_1(...) func_VA(__VA_ARGS__)` now works if I call `func_1(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1});` as you might assume.

I've made a "wrapper" macro that returns `(__VA_ARGS__)` and this allows the macro to work properly with a list init though the string version does have extra brackets. Though I can't get this to work in a way such that you (as the user) do not have to call wrapper on your arrays (which is harder than putting the brakcets in place your self).

Comment: Why do you overload the macro on number of arguments? Just `#define func(...)  func_macro::DebugOutput(__FILE__, ......)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not entirely sure this would work with how the DebugOutput class works. But perhaps I am missing something, could you enlighten me further?

Comment: `#define func(...) func_macro::DebugOutput(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__).print(func_macro::type_name<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(), (__VA_ARGS__))` I don't know at all how DebugOutput works not how it works, you didn't show it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah IK. It uses VA to enable commas inside for something like an initialisation as stated in the comment above `func_VA` I'll be honest I'm not entirely sure how it does that just from looking. Looking through the history there was no specifics for this other than using `...` rather than a normal varaiable.

Comment: `It uses VA` - what is "VA" in this context? What do you want to happen on something like `dbg(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1}, std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1});`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Variadic Arguments (`...`). The idea is that `dbg(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1}, std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1});` gets split into `dbg(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1}); 
 dbg(std::vector<int>{0, 1, 0, 1});` More or less. The problem is that the commas inside the vector no longer work that the macro routes to a "chooser" rather than the old single arg way.

Comment: In C++20, we have [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) to get rid of need of MACRO to know filename/function name/line of a call.

Comment: Can't you change `func_macro::DebugOutput` to use variadic template?

Comment: @Jarod42 that could work though I'm worried about the use in expression then. Currently passing say `myFunc(func()1, 2, 3));` and this will pass all the variables through just fine. Will I be able to do similar with a variadic template?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `DebugOutput::print` to be variadic template, you might do something like:

```
#define func(...)                                                     \
  func_macro::DebugOutput{__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #__VA_ARGS__} \
      .print(__VA_ARGS__)


namespace func_macro
{

struct DebugOutput
{
    const char* filename = nullptr;
    int line = 0;
    const char* funcname = nullptr;
    const char* argsString = nullptr;

    template <typename ... Ts>
    void print(const Ts&... args) const
    {
        std::cout << filename << ":" << line << " in " << funcname << std::endl;
        std::cout << "func(" << argsString << ")\n";

        ((std::cout << typeid(args).name() << ": " << args << std::endl), ...);
    }
};

}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98e9e6a7721f8688)